# Using fields_for in partial throwing undefined method `model_name' for Enumerator:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where an Assignment has a number of Strengths to develop and each Strength has Performance levels.

I am trying to loop through a collection and display the strength name and then a radio button for each of the performance levels so the user can select where they think they are at.

I am passing the collection with the data to a partial to render.

```
<div id="content"><%= render partial: 'focus', locals: {assignment: @assignment}%></div>
```

And in the partial I am trying to use fields_for to loop through the collection like so:

```
<%= form_for @assignment do |f| %>
  <% puts ("Found how many? ").concat(@assignment.AssignmentAssessments.length.to_s) %>

  <div id="content">
    <%= form_for @assignment do |f| %>
      <% puts ("Found how many? ").concat(@assignment.AssignmentAssessments.length.to_s) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "assignment[AssignmentAssessments][]", nil %>
      <%= fields_for @assignment.AssignmentAssessments.each do |a| %>
        <%= strength_name(a.strength_id) %>
        <% Performance.all.each do |p| %>
            <label class="checkbox">
              <%= check_box_tag "assignment[AssignmentAssessments][]", a.id, p.level == a.performance_id, id: dom_id(a) %>
              <%= label_tag dom_id(a), a.id %>
            </label>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

When I get to the statement

```
<%= fields_for @assignment.AssignmentStrengthPerformanceAssessments.each do |asses| %>
```

I am getting `NoMethodError in Assignments#show` and the detail saying `undefined method 'model_name' for Enumerator:Class`

I thought AssignmentStrengthPerformanceAssessments might have been nil so I put the puts in there to write it out to the console - that is returning correct value of 6 from the length call.

The models look like this

```
class AssignmentStrengthPerformanceAssessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignment
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :AssignmentAssessments, class_name: 'AssignmentStrengthPerformanceAssessment'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :AssignmentAssessments
end
```

And before I show anything I am building the collection in my controller like so

```
@assignment.AssignmentAssessments.build(user_id: 0, assignment_id: @assignment.id)
```

Any guidance will be graciously welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Your code in view makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: please respect syntax conventions, please

Comment: have you tried it by using `has_many : assignmentassessments`

Comment: Yeah - same result `undefined method 'model_name' for Enumerator:Class`

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this thanks to a codementor

`fields_for` works with a single model instance and when I was passing it a collection rails couldn't call model_name because it didn't exist on the collection

Working code was ended up being (from the code above)

```
<%= fields_for :assignmentassessments do |field| %>
      <% assignment.assignmentassessments.each do |a| %>
```